# Монтирование раздела в Убунту

Tags: ubuntu, монтирование

У меня есть раздел /dev/sda3 и /dev/sda4 где /dev/sda4 раздел на котором установлена система и на него устанавливаеться все что я скачиваю,как мне можно примонтировать /dev/sda3 к /dev/sda4?

Comment: ```cat /etc/fstab```. Команды ```mount``` и ```umount```.

Comment: Извиняюсь,я новичок в убунту и не знаю что писать в mount

Comment: Вот что пишет при выполнении команды  /mnt/disk: ошибочный тип ФС, ошибочный параметр, ошибочный суперблок на /dev/sda3, не хватает кодовой страницы или вспомогательной программы или другая ошибка. Команда: sudo mount -v /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk

Comment: Я не советую экспериментировать на "живой" системе, если нет познания в области файловых систем и точек монтирования - лучше где-нибудь на виртуальной попробовать. Что касается вашей "проблемы" - если нет навыков с командной строкой, запустите графическую программу (ищите disks в установленных). Там есть и разделы и точки монтирования. Советую почитать в сети, как работать с ней.